# In python, should you use an if for None checks, or use `or`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, styles

Stylistically, is it considered better to do `None` checks using an `if`:

```
if date is None:
    date = datetime.now()
```

or by using an `or`?

```
date = date or datetime.now()
```

The first seems more descriptive but the second seems more elegant.  I understand that the answer to this question could be opinionated, but what I'm asking is **is there an official style recommendation for this?**

Comment: Did you look through https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?

Comment: Yeah I skimmed it and Cmd+F'ed for ' or ', and didn't see anything relevant

Comment: `date = datetime.now() if date is None else date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not being really explicit in the second case. If `date` is *any* non Truthy value, `datetime.now()` will be used.

Your comparisons are actually:

If generically testing against truthy values:

```
if not date:
    date = datetime.now()
# versus
date = date or datetime.now()
# or
date = datetime.now() if date else date
```

Or, checking solely for `None`s:

```
if date is None:
    date = datetime.now()
# versus (as Peter states in a comment)
date = datetime.now() if date is None else date
```

PEP 8 doesn't have any comments on this, if you're only checking explicitly against `None` use `is None`, it is good to be explicit (that's one of the rules in the Zen).

If you're checking on non truthy values, I like `or` as a trick. It might stump some people that aren't familiar with the way Python behaves here, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What's your opinion if this is in a function defined as `def foo(date=None)`, where you're mainly checking if a date has been passed in?

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I personally like the `or` and I've seen examples of it in the standard lib (can't remember where now). Issue is what happens if someone passes `''` or `0`? Would that be valid? If, like I'm guessing, the answer is no, use `or`, if you only want to check for `None`s use `is None`. It is personal taste in the end, `PEP 8` doesn't enforce these things.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case:

```
if date is None:
```

will be `True` only if value of `date` is None. It will not set date as current date if value of date is empty-string, 0, empty-list, etc.

But, `date or datetime.now()` will set the current date even in the case of empty values apart from just `None`. There is difference in the logic :)

Check [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for complete list.

Comment: That's a good point, I should have been more specific in my question.  What's your opinion if this is in a function defined as `def foo(date=None)`, where you're mainly checking if a date has been passed in?

Comment: better go with `return date if date else date.now()` as per me it is more clear showing logical assignment compare to `date or date.now`. But it is opinion based

Comment: Won't date = date or datetime.now() always set date to a Boolean True if it was none? 
if date is None, 
then date = None or "x",
=> date = True.

Comment: @fuzzyhedge: Python don't works that way. try `"hello" or "world"`, you will get your answer

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, if the current date is 0 (maybe a start date), then you'll return date.now().

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, I wasn't aware of that subtlety. Appreciated.

Comment: @fuzzyhedge: Yes, that is what I explained. In that case it will return `date.now()`. Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing . You will find it useful